# When working with tick-boxes, should I use a serialized array or a separate database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a lesson observation system for the school I work at.

The database structure looks like this:

[image: Database structure]

I'm currently developing the input form for the `Observations` table and quite a few of its fields require tick-boxes. For example, the `Focus` field can be any number of twelve options; the `Positive` and `Negative` field can each be any number of nearly twenty options.

In the image above, I've used `VARCHAR` to allow for a `serialize`'d array.

However, I'm starting to wonder if this is the best route to go down, especially considering I may want to do some semi-complex analysis of the data such as `top 5 staff for a specific positive attribute such as behaviour` (which would involve counting the number of `behaviour` attributes each member of staff had under the `Positive` field in the `Observations` table).

Two questions here;

- Should I be using extra tables? For `Focus` I would imagine the first table to have three fields - `ID` (key and auto-increment), `Observation_ID` and `Focus_ID`. The `Focus_ID` would correlate with another table called `focii` or something which would simply have two fields - `Focus_ID` and `Title`. I would need two tables for `Focus` and three tables for `Positive`/`Development` (same options but different logging).
- If I use these extra database tables, what would my SQL statement look like when trying to retrieve the information from the `Observations` table including all associated `focuses`, `positives` and `developments`?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: +1 for clear question and images of database scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should always normalise in this kind of situations. Storing serialised data is hellish if you wanna do calculations or even modifications. (How are you gonna remove the 3rd element?)

Example of a query:

```
SELECT 
    o.id, 
    COUNT(f.id) AS number_of_focusses 
FROM 
    observations o 
INNER JOIN focuses f 
    ON f.observation_id = o.id 
GROUP BY id
```

This would give you the number of 'focus records' belonging to each observation.

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn't even considered the removal of elements! Thanks Robin.

Comment: Robin, how would I go about including the title of the focus in that SQL statement? I.e. if I had the table called "focuses" which logged all of the focuses attached to observations, but then also had a table called "focus_labels" with `ID` and `Title`?